# Options to register a SharePoint 2016 Addin

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, 2016

In SharePoint 2013 we had 2 options

- PowerShell
- or throught https://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection/_layouts/15/Appregnew.aspx

But now, in SharePoint 2016, the second option to register an Addin is not present, or maybe changed the link or the way of doing so.

So, I would like to know what changed from SharePoint 2013 apps to 2016 Addin in terms of infrastructure (certificates, register the add (is still needed) and etc).

Also, I would like to ask if there is another tool to see logs from the apps other than the ULS Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed, including the registration URL, between SharePoint 2013 and 2016.

As for logging, I'd always use ULSViewer for monitoring ULS.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake, I placed the wrong link that I couldnt find in SP2016, which was  http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection/Lists/DraftApps/AllItems.aspx instead of the one on the post.

Comment: So, only the way to trust the app has changed then?